# Puppeteer / headless Chromium "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0" error only in GUI-less environments

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, puppeteer, chromium

I'm using Puppeteer with headless Chromium to login to a certain website and I'm getting the following error when the page tries to fetch some of its JS files (website name hidden intentionally):

```
[0726/133656.950429:INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "object err SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0", source: https://***/_/horizon/p/_next/static/chunks/commons-e5cd62ffd659714024c3.js (1)
```

This only happens when I run the script under Docker locally (Alpine Linux) or on a VPS (Debian), so both no-GUI environments. When I run the same script on my host machine locally (Manjaro Linux, no Docker) - everything runs smoothly, no errors like that. I'm running node v16.x in all cases, Chromium versions are v102 (Docker) and v109 (local host machine), and here are my Puppeteer settings:

```js
{
        headless: 'new',
        args: [
            '--no-sandbox',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--disable-features=DefaultPassthroughCommandDecoder',
            '--disable-web-security',
            '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins',
            '--disable-site-isolation-trials',
        ],
        dumpio: true,
        pipe: true,
    };
```

Ultimately I need this to run on a VPS. I've been trying to solve this for a few days to no avail, please help.

Comment: Is it possible that something is coming along with your user agent and it's serving you an HTML page instead of a JSON response?

Comment: That error usually occurs when HTML is passed to a JSON parser. Why you are getting HTML instead of JSON is not something we can tell you specifically. The only thing we can suggest is to track which request is causing the error and see what it is about that request that is causing it to return HTML.